# Using Swift 3 in XCode 8, how to control a UITableView subview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm very, very new to Swift/Xcode and just flapping around in the dark... I'm so lost. I've got a screen that loads, and inside of it is a View with two subviews: MKMapView and UITAbleView.

The map loads perfectly, but I cannot seem to correctly control the table and load it with data because the app crashes when I click on "Show Nearby Restaurants".

Here is the full debugging traceback I'm getting:

```
2016-10-10 10:28:59.516777 Restaurants[93314:1607613] bundleid: com.Example.Restaurants, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.517100 Restaurants[93314:1607613] subsystem: com.apple.siri, category: Intents, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.524112 Restaurants[93314:1607821] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.526181 Restaurants[93314:1607821] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.535733 Restaurants[93314:1607818] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.548057 Restaurants[93314:1607613] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.564 Restaurants[93314:1607613] Unknown class _TtC22Restaurant18RootViewController in Interface Builder file.
2016-10-10 10:28:59.662817 Restaurants[93314:1607818] subsystem: com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.676411 Restaurants[93314:1607823] subsystem: com.apple.network, category: , enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.676674 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 1 restaurants.example.com 80
2016-10-10 10:28:59.677043 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] tcp_connection_start 1 starting
2016-10-10 10:28:59.677355 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_connection_create creating connection to restaurants.example.com:80
2016-10-10 10:28:59.677626 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7ff21100b610
2016-10-10 10:28:59.677833 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] __nw_connection_start_block_invoke 1 starting
2016-10-10 10:28:59.678105 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [1 restaurants.example.com:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-10 10:28:59.678293 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2016-10-10 10:28:59.678993 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [1 restaurants.example.com:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-10 10:28:59.679235 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2016-10-10 10:28:59.679788 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
2016-10-10 10:28:59.680194 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for hostname: restaurants.example.com, ifindex: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.680805 Restaurants[93314:1607818] subsystem: com.apple.SystemConfiguration, category: SCPreferences, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.681819 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_resolver startWithHandler:] [1 restaurants.example.com:80 waiting resolver (satisfied)]
2016-10-10 10:28:59.682059 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:start_dns
2016-10-10 10:28:59.682582 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue Starting host resolution restaurants.example.com:80, flags 0x4000d000
2016-10-10 10:28:59.687044 Restaurants[93314:1607613] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:28:59.876823 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com. addr=23.23.196.165:0 ttl=75
2016-10-10 10:28:59.877069 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_resolver_start_query_timer Starting 1s query timer to receive all address families for restaurants.example.com:80
2016-10-10 10:28:59.877302 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_resolver_start_crazy_eyeballs_timer Received IPv4 result first, performing crazy eyeballs: waiting 50ms on IPv6 for restaurants.example.com:80
2016-10-10 10:28:59.999464 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] __nw_resolver_start_crazy_eyeballs_timer_block_invoke Crazy eyeballs timer fired: did not receive IPv6 in time, reporting only IPv4 result for restaurants.example.com:80
2016-10-10 10:28:59.999686 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_resolver_cancel_crazy_eyeballs_timer Cancelling crazy eyeballs timer for restaurants.example.com
2016-10-10 10:29:00.000005 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] resolver is in_progress
2016-10-10 10:29:00.000373 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 23.23.196.165:80
2016-10-10 10:29:00.001412 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Updated endpoint list is (23.23.196.165:80)
2016-10-10 10:29:00.001998 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:receive_dns
2016-10-10 10:29:00.002690 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting child endpoint 23.23.196.165:80
2016-10-10 10:29:00.003071 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting next child endpoint in 178ms
2016-10-10 10:29:00.003507 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-10 10:29:00.003841 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 23.23.196.165:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-10 10:29:00.004089 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2016-10-10 10:29:00.004526 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-10 10:29:00.004791 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 23.23.196.165:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-10 10:29:00.005035 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2016-10-10 10:29:00.005323 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for hostname: <nil>, ifindex: 0
2016-10-10 10:29:00.006192 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 waiting socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-10 10:29:00.006437 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] creating socket
2016-10-10 10:29:00.006818 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-10 10:29:00.007388 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Attached flow protocol
2016-10-10 10:29:00.007722 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 23.23.196.165:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-10 10:29:00.008528 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2016-10-10 10:29:00.017739 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554) hostname=us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com. addr=::.0 ttl=77
2016-10-10 10:29:00.017976 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_resolver_cancel_query_timer Cancelling query timer for restaurants.example.com
2016-10-10 10:29:00.018285 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] resolver is complete
2016-10-10 10:29:00.018545 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Keeping started endpoint 23.23.196.165:80
2016-10-10 10:29:00.018797 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Updated endpoint list is (23.23.196.165:80)
2016-10-10 10:29:00.019050 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:receive_dns
2016-10-10 10:29:00.166619 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x800
2016-10-10 10:29:00.166833 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received CONNECTED event
2016-10-10 10:29:00.167079 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_socket_setup_notsent_lowat Set TCP_NOTSENT_LOWAT(16384)
2016-10-10 10:29:00.167332 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected
2016-10-10 10:29:00.167891 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-10 10:29:00.168068 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied
2016-10-10 10:29:00.168271 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 23.23.196.165:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-10 10:29:00.168527 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2016-10-10 10:29:00.168796 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 ready resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2016-10-10 10:29:00.169019 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 ready resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 23.23.196.165:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-10 10:29:00.169219 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 23.23.196.165:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:changed_viability
2016-10-10 10:29:00.169415 Restaurants[93314:1607818] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 restaurants.example.com:80 ready resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:changed_viability
2016-10-10 10:29:00.169714 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] __tcp_connection_start_block_invoke 1 sending event TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_CONNECTED in response to state ready and error (null)
2016-10-10 10:29:00.169913 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] tcp_connection_event_notify 1 event: TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_CONNECTED, reason: nw_connection event, should deliver: true
2016-10-10 10:29:00.170271 Restaurants[93314:1607823] [] tcp_connection_get_statistics DNS: 320ms/323ms since start, TCP: 160ms/490ms since start, TLS: 0ms/0ms since start
2016-10-10 10:29:27.664045 Restaurants[93314:1607613] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:29:27.664832 Restaurants[93314:1607613] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Gesture, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:29:27.665446 Restaurants[93314:1607613] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:29:27.665830 Restaurants[93314:1607613] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureExclusion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-10 10:29:27.846 Restaurants[93314:1607613] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-Wgc-6W-3v8" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010819f34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001078d821e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108208265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001089e383c -[UITableViewController loadView] + 638
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000108763c4c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010876a4d6 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 118
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000108795393 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1290
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001087a6008 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 697
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001087a719b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010899e1b7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000108687344 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fc9ecdc -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fc927a0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fc9261e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fc2062c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fc4d713 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001085bc067 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 206
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000108dcbb30 __handleEventQueue + 5672
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108144311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010812959c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108128a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108128494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010fb81a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001085c2f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    24  Restaurants              0x0000000106d157af main + 111
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b5d468d start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here is my code that controls the view "NearbyDataViewController.swift":

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class NearbyDataViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var nearbyMap: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nearbyTable: UITableView!

    // json from server
    var nearbyRestaurantsJSON:JSON = []

    // constant for holding the user's location
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //
        // Set table view
        //
        self.nearbyTable.delegate = self
        self.nearbyTable.dataSource = self
        self.nearbyTable.allowsSelection = true

        ///////////////////
        //   Load Map    //
        ///////////////////

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.nearbyMap.showsUserLocation = true

        ///////////////////
        // Query Server  //
        ///////////////////


        //
        // Request data for nearby restaurants
        //
        let latText = String(format: "%f", (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
        let lonText = String(format: "%f", (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
        print("XXXXXXXXX USER LOCATION XXXXXXXXX: " + latText + ", " + lonText)


        let server_url:String = "http://www.example.com/&lat=" + latText + "&lon=" + lonText

        Alamofire.request(server_url).responseJSON { response in

            // load resposne into into SwiftyJSON to parse JSON
            let json = JSON(response.result.value)

            // show response
            self.nearbyRestaurantsJSON = json["objects"]
            debugPrint(self.nearbyRestaurantsJSON)


            // load the table
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.nearbyTable.reloadData()
                return
            }

        }
    }

    //
    // Enable the location manager
    //

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005))
        self.nearbyMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    //
    // Table Data Parse
    //
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nearbyRestaurantsJSON.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        // change the label text to the restaurant name
        cell.textLabel?.text = nearbyRestaurantsJSON[indexPath.row]["rest_name"].string

        // get length of inspection reports and find most recent
        var insp_dates = [Date?]()
        let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in (nearbyRestaurantsJSON[indexPath.row]["onlinereports"]) {
            // convert string to date
            let date_string = subJson["insp_date"].string
            let dt = dateformatter.date(from: date_string!)
            insp_dates.append(dt)
        }

        let dt = insp_dates.sorted{ (firstThing, secondThing) -> Bool in
            firstThing! > secondThing!
            }.first

        let dt_str = dateformatter.string(from: dt!!)

        // match the date to the json object
        for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in (nearbyRestaurantsJSON[indexPath.row]["onlinereports"]) {
            if subJson["insp_date"].string == dt_str {
                if Double(subJson["insp_score"].string!)! + 1 < 37.0 {
                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "thumbs_down")
                }
                else {
                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "thumbs_up")
                }
            }
        }

        return cell
    }



}
```

My storyboard layout:
[image]

Delegates/Outlets for the root view (NearbyDataViewController):
[image]

Delegates/Outlets for nearbyMap:
[image]

Delegates/Outlets for nearbyTable:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NearbyDataViewController is subclassed from UITableViewController, which requires it's root view to be UITableView, which is obviously not, since you have MKMapView there as well.

So you should:

1. Subclass from plain UIViewController,
2. Set delegate and dataSource manually:

[image]

3. Declare that you implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource (and of course implement their methods, as you did).

`class NearbyDataViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate`

Comment: Hi @alex, thanks for helping. I think that I made the changes you instructed, so my class now looks your example. I didn't change the dataSource (should I have?). The problem I'm facing now is with the override functions listed under the comment "Table Data Parse": numberOfSections and tableView. Xcode reports, "Method does not override any method from its superclass". I'm not sure how to solve this because my understanding of Swift is so poor. I tried to assign the function to a variable and then call that from viewDidLoad(), or chaining the methods to self.nearbyTable ... but neither worked.

Comment: Just remove "override" keyword. This word had sense before because those methods were implemented in UITableViewController, but they aren't in UIViewController.

Comment: Oh wow... yeah, that was not intuitive to me at all and was driving me insane. I don't understand how the functions are being triggered without the override, so I need to do some more reading on Swift. Seriously, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The error is explained on the last logged line:

```
2016-10-10 10:29:27.846 Restaurants[93314:1607613] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
'-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with 
identifier "UIViewController-Wgc-6W-3v8" from storyboard "Main", but didn't
get a UITableView.
```

This means that you're using a `UITableViewController`, but that controller's `view` in the storyboard is not an instance of `UITableView`. `UITableViewController` expects it's `view` property to always be connected to a `UITableView` (or a subclass thereof).